# What is the difference between WSAENOBUFS and WSAEWOULDBLOCK?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I tried to `send()` a 1.5 GB buffer on a non-blocking sockets (just for testing purposes :), but it gave me `WSAENOBUFS` error and not `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSAEWOULDBLOCK refers to the socket send buffer being full, which specifically means that the receiver is slow, i.e. a remote condition.

WSAENOBUFS refers to any *other* buffer or resource shortage, which is a local condition.